# "This field cannot be blank" even if the field is not empty?

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
class Test(PolymorphicModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = [
            'title',
        ]
def clean_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
    if len(title) < 3:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please, enter at least 3 symbols!")
```

Okay, when try to submit the form with text, like "aa" it shows error **"Please, enter at least 3 symbols!"** it works fine, but when add more than 3 symbols it returns me **This field cannot be blank** which comes from Model, because there is no `blank=True`, but field is not empty, I'm confused.

Comment: You forgot to *return* the `title` in your `clean_title` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django's `clean_xxx` methods expect you to return the cleaned value you want to use, in your case it's None.
Also, a better approach is to use `self.add_error` and not raise a ValidationError.

Your code should look like this:

```py
def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data["title"]
    if len(title) < 3:
        self.add_error("title", "Please, enter at least 3 symbols!")
    return title
```

Comment: Nice, what about if I have multiple fields validation, shoul I return 'field' each time ?